# How to make application properties pick from environment variables in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker image with env variables that I set in the docker-compose file. But they are not mapping with the application properties.Could someone please explain me where i went wrong.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM java:8-jre-alpine
ARG TEST_DB_USERNAME
ARG TEST_DB_PASSWORD
ARG TEST_SERVER_PORT
ARG TEST_DATASOURCE_DRIVER
ARG TEST_DATASOURCE_URL
ARG TEST_DATABASE_PLATFORM
ARG TEST_PROFILE

ENV spring.datasource.url $TEST_DATASOURCE_URL
ENV spring.datasource.username $TEST_DB_USERNAME
ENV spring.datasource.password $TEST_DB_PASSWORD
ENV spring.datasource.driver-class-name $TEST_DATASOURCE_DRIVER
ENV spring.jpa.database-platform $TEST_DATABASE_PLATFORM
ENV spring.profiles.active $TEST_PROFILE
ENV server.port $TEST_SERVER_PORT

ADD target/facilities-management.jar facilities-management.jar
EXPOSE $TEST_SERVER_PORT
ENTRYPOINT  ["java", "-jar", "facilities-management.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

    volumes:
      postgres_data: {}
      postgres_backup: {}
    services:
      postgres:
        build: ../postgres
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        expose:
          - 5432 # expose the postgres port out so we can attached to the db from the real world. Only for development?
        volumes:
          - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          - postgres_backup:/backups
        restart: unless-stopped
        env_file:
          - .env
      test-server:
          build:
            context: ../../../test-management
          ports:
            - 8080:8080
          restart: unless-stopped
          depends_on:
            - postgres
```

**.env**

```
#TEST Environment Variables
TEST_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres
TEST_SERVER_PORT=8081
TEST_DATASOURCE_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
TEST_DB_USERNAME=postgres
TEST_DB_PASSWORD=123456
TEST_DATABASE_PLATFORM=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
TEST_PROFILE=sql_server
```

I am getting the following error when i do docker-compose up

**error:**

```
There is no active profile set

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE.
Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this after env_file: directive like below

```
....
env_file:
      - .env
environment:
spring.datasource.url $TEST_DATASOURCE_URL
spring.datasource.username $TEST_DB_USERNAME
spring.datasource.password $TEST_DB_PASSWORD
......
```

Because environmental variables won't be persisted during build time.

Comment: I am  stiill getting the same error     
environment:
      - spring.datasource.url $FACILITY_DATASOURCE_URL
      - spring.datasource.username $FACILITY_DB_USERNAME
      - spring.datasource.password $FACILITY_DB_PASSWORD.
Do i need to write anything in application.properties file for mapping?